# MANETs (Random Walk, Random Direction, etc.) in NS2

Tags: models, ns2, mobility

I am working on a project that requires simulating MANET models such as (Random Walk, Random Direction, etc.) in NS2 Simulator (I installed NS 2.34).

Actually, it is the first time that I use this tool. As I have read, NS2 supports Random Way Point Mobility Model.

What about other mobility models? how can I simulate them in NS2?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Where are you network guys?!

Comment: I got it.. I could do that using another tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following tool which can support Random Direct and Random Walk:

[RandomTrip project](http://icawww1.epfl.ch/RandomTrip/)